# Mongoid embedded collection response to :find

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm sending serialized data to a class which need to access a Mongoid document which may or may not be embedded.

In case of embedded document, I'm accepting a variable number of arguments which I `reduce` to get the embedded document.

The code is pretty simple:

```
def perform(object, *arguments)
  @opts = arguments.extract_options!
  @object = arguments.reduce(object){|object, args| object.public_send(*args)}
  # [...]
```

I used `public_send` because AFAIK I only need to call public methods.

However, when I try to access an embedded document I have some really strange result where `@object` is an enumerator.

After some debugging, this is what I found that for any root document `object` and an embedded collection `items`, I have:

```
object.items.public_send(:find)
# => #<Enumerator: ...>
object.items.send(:find) # or __send__
# => nil
```

The method called is not the same at all when I call `public_send` or `send`!

- How is it even possible?
- Is it normal? Is that a bug?

---

`public_send` seems to invoke the `find` method of `Array` (`Enumerable`) but `send` (or `__send__`) invokes the `find` method of Mongoid

---

Edit: simple reproductible case:

```
require 'mongoid'

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :groups
end

class Group
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embedded_in :user
end

Mongoid.load_configuration({
  sessions: {
    default: {
      database: 'send_find',
      hosts: [
        'localhost:27017'
      ]
    }
  }
})

user = User.create(name: 'john')
user.groups.create(name: 'g1')
user.groups.create(name: 'g2')

puts "public_send :find"
puts user.groups.public_send(:find).inspect
# => #<Enumerator: [#<Group _id: 5530dea57735334b69010000, name: "g1">, #<Group _id: 5530dea57735334b69020000, name: "g2">]:find>
puts "send :find"
puts user.groups.send(:find).inspect
# => nil
puts "__send__ :find"
puts user.groups.__send__(:find).inspect
# => nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a few hours of debugging, I found that it is actually a bug in Mongoid.

The relation is not an array but a proxy around the array, which delegates most methods to the array.

As `public_send` was also delegated but not `send` and `__send__`, the behavior was not the same.

For more information, see my [pull request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/pull/4040) and the associated commit.

Comment: @JordanLapp the repository moved, I updated the link.
Anyway, the merge request has been accepted since then